# Spreadsheet - query-importrange sort by date and keep text in the same column

Tags: sorting, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I am using 3 different spreadsheets which i have linked to a third spreadsheet where it shows up specific columns shorted by date asc (col2). The problem is that in the initial spreadsheets (where i importing the data from) the col30 (which i am trying to sort as col2 in final spreadsheet) has dates and text. What i need is that in the final spreadsheet to have the date sorted and to show also the text (in the col2 of final spreadsheet-which imports data from col30 of the 3 different spreadsheets).
The dates are sorted but neither the text appears nor the rest of the data which are in the same row with the date (on initial spreadsheets). The total data of the columns chosen when "Col6 CONTAINS '"&$B$1&"' are only appears when i put a date on col30 on initial spreadsheets. Otherwise, when it is no date but onlly text on col30 it doesn't return any variables.

Any suggestions? Thank you in advance.

What i have tried so far, which works without showing the text that i need to be shown:

`=QUERY(QUERY({IMPORTRANGE("url1 ";"sheet1!A2:AJ1000");IMPORTRANGE("url2 ";"sheet2!A2:AJ1000");IMPORTRANGE("url3 ";"sheet3!A2:AJ1000")};"Select Col5,Col30,Col31,Col21,Col22,Col23,Col24,Col34,Col35,Col36 where Col6 CONTAINS '"&$B$1&"'");"Select * where Col2 is not null order by Col2")`

Comment: Is there any reason why you are using 2 queries instead of using a single one? (eg. `=query(..., "select * where Col6 contains '"&$B$1$"' and Col2 is not null order by Col2")`)

Comment: The first query refers to the "initial" 3 different spradsheets and since the "Col2 is not null order by Col2" is located and refers to the "end" spreadsheet (which collects all the data) i used another query to have the imported data sorted after the importrange function. Meaning that Col6 is in "initial" spreadsheets and col2 on the "end" spreadsheet.

Comment: @Nek Please read how to and [share a test sheet](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/138383/117311) so as you can be easier helped.

Comment: @marikamitsos Thank you, the links are:  https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1mpZ46kOXBHrYl4lQO2o8ZF33yMhro1t0Tq94L737LbM/edit?usp=sharing and https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1usAXftvFrpCHz7LN43avWrWqSIO14iKM-pgwuG9jMeE/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what I believe you are trying to achieve:

```
=QUERY(
  {
    IMPORTRANGE("1usAXftvFrpCHz7LN43avWrWqSIO14iKM-pgwuG9jMeE";"Sheet1!A2:AJ")\
    ARRAYFORMULA(
      TO_TEXT(
        IMPORTRANGE("1usAXftvFrpCHz7LN43avWrWqSIO14iKM-pgwuG9jMeE";"Sheet1!AD2:AE")
      )
    )
  };
  "SELECT Col5,Col37,Col38,Col21,Col22,Col23,Col24,Col34,Col35,Col36 WHERE Col6='"&$B$1&"' AND Col37 is not null ORDER BY Col30, Col31"
)
```

Let's unpack the changes:

1. Remove the outer query. You don't need it. Instead add the condition and order by in the first query.
2. change the range to be an open ended one
3. Add columns with the text version of the dates / times.

The last point is important as query only supports a single type at a time. This means that when you were querying over the date and time, you were loosing the text (because they are of another type). Adding 2 more columns and forcing them to be text allows you to add them in the result without loosing information and keeping the originals allows you to order by them.

### References

- [QUERY (Docs editors help)](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093343)
- [TO_TEXT (Docs editors help)](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094285)
- [ARRAYFORMULA (Docs editors help)](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093275)

Comment: Did you try it? Did it work as you expected?

Comment: I haven't manage to try it yet due to really limited time. But i will and get back asap. My problem though is that i would like to avoid new columns for that reason and this addition will not return a result on the "end" spreadsheet with the entries sorted (ascending/descending) with the "postponed" word shown accordingly after or before the sorted dates. So, i was wondering if another formula like "filter" would return such a result. i have tried within the same spreadsheet and it seems to return both dates and text in the same column but i dont'n know how to specifically

Comment: Thank you, i moved forward and added a few more loops with more spreadsheets and it seems to work just fine!...I haven't managed though to look more into the "TO_TEXT" and "ARRAYFORMULA" or study more the code that you wrote. I have got a bit confused with the Col37 and Col38 that you added but i will study further the code to figure out how it works. Furthermore, (not a major issue) but could you suggest on how i could have the " postponed" word sorted after the dates?Thank you for your time!